# Geopy chokes on ASCII characters

Tags: python, geopy

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()

place = 'Greece'

location = geolocator.geocode(place)
print location
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/temp/Test.py", line 10, in <module>
print location
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Second try with decoding:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()

place = 'Greece'
place_decoded = place.decode('utf-8')

location = geolocator.geocode(place)
print location
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/temp/Test.py", line 10, in <module>
print location
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Check type of place_decoded:

```
print type(place_decoded)
<type 'unicode'>
```

The word Greece should not give any trouble. Anyone having an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found that the easy solution is working with english :)

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()
place = 'Greece'
location = geolocator.geocode(place, language='en')
print location
'Greece'
```

Answer (score 2):

just letting you know, if you want to know what parameters function can take you can type:

```
print geolocator.geocode.func_code.co_varnames

'('self', 'query', 'exactly_one', 'timeout', 'addressdetails', 'language', 'geometry', 'params', 'url')'
```